# How can I fully uninstall eclipse?

Tags: uninstall, eclipse

I installed eclipse from the software for Ubuntu, then when I wanted uninstall from console it shows the message 'The package "eclipse" it's not installed.' so I don't know what can I do. Even I deleted the folder  '.eclipse' and nothing.

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get purge eclipse`?

Comment: Yes I did, but it's says the same message. I've tried purge, autoremove, remove and the same story